# removing the default option from a zend form

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm using Zend Framework 1.12, manipulating a form with some select options. The problem is I've been asked to remove the default option which shows up at the beginning in the form so that the select menu is empty, at the beginning, but so that it could be filled only with three values. My code is below:

```
 $tipo = new Zend_Form_Element_Select ( 'tipo', array (
            'onchange' => 'checkServer(this.value);'
                    ) );
    $tipo->setLabel ( 'Kerio Product' )->setRequired ()->addMultiOptions ( array (
            '1' => 'Connect',
            '2' => 'Control',
            '3' => 'Operator'
    ) );

 $this->addElement( $tipo )
```

$this_setValue(""); doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

give a try to this code (you need to extend Zend_Form in your class).

```
$this->addElement('select', 'KerioProduct', array(

        'multiOptions' => array('' => "") + Zend_Registry::get('config')->lists->yourProducts->toArray()/* if you store your options in a file: 'connect, control... in your case: OR create an array 1=>connect , 2=>control... */,

        'required' => true,
        'validators' => array (
                            'NotEmpty' => array (
                                'validator' => 'NotEmpty',
                                'options' => array (
                                    'messages' => $tr->_('select  a product ')
                                )
                            )
                        )
    ));
```

hope it helps.

Comment: what does $TR stand for?

Comment: used to translate later, you remove it from the code messages=>"..."

Answer (score 1):

You could set null or "" as first option in like this:

> ->addMultiOptions(array('0' => '', '1' => 'Connect'....

Comment: it should validate or not? it depends if this filed should be required.

Comment: no it shouldn't validate, this field is required but it shoudl be emty when the form shows up at first.. I'm looking for a validator, but somehow messy

Comment: it will be empty the select value is " ". Then you have to set valid values from 1-3.

Answer (score 1):

If You want the Select menu to be empty, you need to set the Register array validator of zend forms to false;  And the  Select Element  will be empty and can go with out validation error.

You can that by doing the following.

```
$tipo = new Zend_Form_Element_Select ( 'tipo', array (
                'onchange' => 'checkServer(this.value);'
                ) 
                );
$tipo->setLabel ( 'Kerio Product' )
     ->setRequired () // You don't need this in this case
     ->setRegisterInArrayValidator(false);
```

That sets your select element empty with out getting array validation error. How you want add the selections option, depends on you you can do it on controller or in view .

```
 ->addMultiOptions ( array (
            '1' => 'Connect',
            '2' => 'Control',
            '3' => 'Operator'
    ) )
```

I hope that adds some to your question